# List all shared users of a particular presentation/doc on Google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We need a comprehensive list of people who have gained "Shared" viewing privileges of a particular presentation/doc on Google drive. We have a screen shot but it may NOT be enough. How may we retrieve this information programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

The attributes attached to a `File` object include three user-related items:

- **Owner** - a single `User` object, retrieved using `File.getOwner()`.
- **Editors** - an array of `Users` who have editing privileges on the File, retrieved using `File.getEditors()`. Includes the Owner.
- **Viewers** - an array of `Users` with read-only viewing privileges on the File, retrieved using `File.getViewers()`. Includes the Owner.

These can be obtained programmatically only by the file owner.

The following function is a utility from [Restore trashed google drive files to a target folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518410/restore-trashed-google-drive-files-to-a-target-folder/14541247#14541247).  The `getFileInfo()` function returns an object with attributes of the provided `File` or `Folder`, including the Editors and Viewers. It ignores the owner in the Editors and Viewers lists. Feel free to adapt this to your own situation. Note: it relies on additional utility functions you'll find [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/4644369).

```js
/**
 * Return an object containing relevant information about the given file.
 * See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file.
 * From: https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/4644369
 *
 * @param {Object}  file   File or Folder object to examine.
 *
 * @return {Object}        Interesting file attributes.
 * <pre>{
 *     id: unique id (ID) of the folder or file
 *     name: the name of the File
 *     size: the size of the File
 *     type: The type of the file
 *     created: date that the File was created
 *     description: the description of the File
 *     owner: user id of the owner of the File
 *     otherViewers: list of user ids of viewers of the File, w/o owner
 *     otherEditors: list of user ids of editors of the File, w/o owner
 * }</pre>
 */
function getFileInfo (file) {
  var fileInfo = {
    id: file.getId(),
    name: file.getName(), 
    size: file.getSize(),
    type: (file.getMimeType) ? docTypeToText_(file.getMimeType()) : "folder",  // DriveApp Folders don't have getMimeType() method.
    created: file.getDateCreated(),
    description: file.getDescription(),
    owner: userNames([file.getOwner()],false),
    otherViewers: userNames(file.getViewers(),true),
    otherEditors: userNames(file.getEditors(),true)
    };
  return fileInfo;
}
```

Here's an example of a file's attributes:

```js
{ "id": "0B2kSPNhhUowaRGZKY3VGLUZCREk",
  "name": "Rescued Files",
  "size": 0,
  "type": "folder",
  "created": "2016-06-13T20:18:14.526Z",
  "description": "",
  "owner": "user@example.com",
  "otherViewers": "none",
  "otherEditors": "none"
}
```

#### Bonus content

Below is a script that scans all files and folders in your Google Drive, generating logs with the user information. (It has no provision for avoiding timeouts, caveat emptor!)

```js
/**
 * Generate logs with user sharing info for all files & folders.
 */
function showSharing() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();

  while (files.hasNext() || folders.hasNext()) {
    var iterator = files.hasNext() ? files : folders;

    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(getFileInfo(iterator.next())));
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated to use DriveApp, as original version use the now-deprecated DocsList.

Answer (score 0):

Open Share, Copy all the users, Paste values only an a new Spreadsheet.