# Strange permission issue with getOwner method in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

When using this line of code in a Google Apps Script

```
  var user = folders[n].getOwner().getEmail()
```

I get an error saying I am not authorized to perform such an action (your version may vary, I am translating from italian).

What gives? I am just retrieving an information, such as the owner of a folder.

---

When the script processes a folder I own, the error does not arise, the error arises when it encounters a folder not of mine. The matter is that this line of code is just for spotting folders which are not of mine, to avoid issuing method that would correctly rise an error, like `setTrashed`. The script looks for empty folders to delete them, but I cannot delete folders I am not the owner of of course. And yes I am into Google apps for business, does it make some difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any specifc warning about `file.getOwner().getEmail()`, but there is for [Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_session#getActiveUser).

> In limited-privilege executions (such as in response to onOpen or
>   onEdit), we only return the identity of the active user if both the
>   user and the script owner are part of the same domain. This is to
>   protect the privacy of consumer users, who may not want their email
>   address exposed.

I have no problem with this in a consumer account.

The following function is an excerpt from [a gist I posted for a previous question](https://gist.github.com/4644369). It wraps the call to `.getEmail()` (or `getUserLoginId()` if you prefer) in a `try ... catch` block, so it avoids errors for users crossing Apps Domains.

```
function getFileInfo (file,fileType) {
  var fileInfo = {
    id: file.getId(),
    name: file.getName(), 
    size: file.getSize(),
    type: (fileType == "file") ? docTypeToText_(file.getFileType()) : "folder",
    created: file.getDateCreated(),
    description: file.getDescription(),
    owner: file.getOwner()
  }
  try {
    fileInfo.owner = file.getOwner().getEmail()//.getUserLoginId()
  } catch(e)
  {
    // Possible permission problem
    fileInfo.owner = "unknown";
  }
  return fileInfo;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Since this was first posted, something has changed. Now my consumer account encounters the aforementioned error when trying to access `getOwner()` for a file shared from another account. (March 3, 2013)

Comment: Bingo, I guess that does the trick. Forgive me, but I am an absolute beginner and I do not even know how to handle exceptions. I will try to implement it into my script to work at least into those folders of mine. Since I am a noob into stack-overflow as well, would you tell me what should I do to give you reputation and such? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, I had searched for good source of information about the try... catch block into javascript but that document of your is better by far. Thank you for telling me about the block limits of use, as well. Have a nice weekend.