# how to find files not owned by me in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Drive one can search files 'Not owned by me'. 
I need access to this from Google Apps Script. 
I already tried DocsList.find("Not 'me' in owner"); which appears to be the way to do it in the drive API, but without success (in fact that gets me files with me as owner.) I also replaced me with my email address, with and without quotes, but again without success.

Does anyone know if this is possible (other than by iterating all files and checking getOwner().getEmail() manually, which would take far too long given the enormous amount of files owned by this specific user.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the updated answer as of now is to use DriveApp.searchFiles(params) (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String) ).
Code is something like:

```
 // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive that shared with me
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('sharedWithMe');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This function will return an array of all files shared with you. It uses the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), which must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

```js
/**
 * Get array of files on user's Google Drive that have been shared with them.
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947340/1677912
 *
 * @returns   {Array}   Array of file resources
 *                      (see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)
 */
function getSharedWithMe() {
  var optionalArgs = {q:"sharedWithMe=true"};
  var sharedFiles = Drive.Files.list(optionalArgs);
  debugger;  // pause in debugger
  return sharedFiles.items;
}
```

You can do the same thing without code, by using the Google Drive SDK "Explorer".

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541247/1677912) that used this technique to get a list of trashed files.

You'll find the [Files List API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) at the bottom of the Google Drive SDK documentation page for Files:list. For information about search terms, see [Search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). For our purposes, we'll just use `sharedWithMe`.

[image: Screenshot query]

If you leave "fields" blank, you'll get everything that's known about the shared files. You can expand and collapse the results using hard-to-see minus sign tags. But it's helpful to limit the output. I used `items(id,selfLink,owners/displayName)`. Here's how that looks:

[image: Screenshot results]

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I needed the query not ('MYEMAILADDRESS' in owners) in that call, but the resulting json is exactly what I needed in my appscript to do what I want.