# Google API, retrieve parent folder names from FolderIterator - unexpected Timeout

Tags: google-apps-script

reusing an example provided here on Stackoverflow, I successfully populated a google spreadsheet with a list of all Google App files (docs & spreadsheets) in my ownership, but I'm apparently unable to iterate into the parent FolderIterator to retrieve a list of all the containing folders.

**It's my first time ever with google scripts, so I may have made some horribly obvious mistake..**. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    /**
    * Get array of files in user's ownership, and write
    * into currently active sheet.
    * MODIFIED From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14541247/1677912
    * 
    * @returns   {Object[]}   Array of DriveApp file objects
    */
    function getOwnedFiles() {
      var trashedSearch = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners');
      var files = [];
      files.push(["ID","File Name","Parents","URL"]);
      while (trashedSearch.hasNext()) {
        var file = trashedSearch.next();
      files.push([file.getId(),file.getName(),ParentString(file.getParents()),file.getUrl()]);
    }

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, files.length, files[0].length)
     .setValues(files);
    return files;
    }

    function ParentString(MyFoldIter) {
    var ParFolderList=""
    while ( MyFoldIter.hasNext() ) {
     var folder = MyFoldIter.next();
     ParFolderList=ParFolderList+" "+folder.getName();
    }
    return ParFolderList;
    }
```

It worked perfectly, taking a few minutes, until I added the "Parents" column and the ParentString function. 
Then, any execution ends with a timeout message: "Exceeded maximum execution time".
Any hint?

Many thanks and all the best to everybody!

Comment: It seems that It was an actual timeout, not a mistake in the code. I solved the thing bypassing the "fill an array" phase and outputting the rows one by one directly on the spreadsheet, in the while trashedSearch.hasNext() loop.

Comment: Only question remaining: even though I'm cycling with a while loop through the FolderIterator, all I get is the folder immediately above. I expected to get a list of container folders up to the root of my drive...